# How do i set Timers to spawn Objects at a RandomX

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

Im making a game where Meteorites fall from the sky and my plane has to dodge them. So far all i can do is make 1 meteorite fall. Some1 please show me the code for setting up timers to make objects spawn and fall from a randomX. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one simple way to do it:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, spawnMeteor);
timer.start();

function spawnMeteor(e:Event):void{
    const SCREEN_WIDTH:Number = 480;
    var randomX:Number = Math.random() * SCREEN_WIDTH;
    var meteor:Meteor = new Meteor(randomX, -85);
    world.add(meteor);
}
```